# How to show the content of a dialog without shadow?

Tags: kotlin, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

I am displaying a Dialog with Jetpack Compose in my application. The Dialog contains a Google map. The problem is that this map appears dark, as if it has a shadow on it:

[image]

If you notice, it is displayed in exactly the same way as what is below the Dialog. How can I make this map appear clear without any shadow?

My code:

Dialog:

```
@Composable
fun DialogCustom(
    data: Data
    onDismiss: () -> Unit
) {

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = onDismiss) {

        Card(
            backgroundColor = Color.Green,
            elevation = 20.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    horizontal = 20.dp,
                    vertical = 8.dp
                )
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {

                CustomCardTitle(
                    data= data
                    color = Color.Green
                )

                CustomMap(
                    lat = data.lat,
                    lon = data.lon
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Map:

```
@Composable
fun CustomMap(
    lat: Double,
    lon: Double
) {

    val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifeCycle()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            {
                mapView
            }
        ) {
            mapView.getMapAsync {
                val map = it
                map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false
                map.addMarker(marker(title, lat, lon, 250f))
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(lat, lon), 16f))
                map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try placing your Column (inside of CustomMap) in a Surface.

Comment: It doesn't work either, it still looks dark

Comment: How are you displaying the map in the dialog? Is it referencing the same map below the dialog or are you creating a new map inside the dialog? If you are referencing the existing map below the dialog, then in all likelihood Compose is including the dark overlay that it uses when the dialog appears. Try creating a completely different map  instance for the dialog.

Comment: It is a new map.

Comment: Are you setting the background color of the Column? If you are, what exactly is the value you are using?

Comment: What Column? In CustomMap? In CustomMap the background color of the Column is White

Comment: Are you setting it to Color.White or are you setting the hex value? If it's the hex value, please post the value.